# Updating the Value for a Key in an NSMutableOrderedSet object

Tags: ios, iphone

I have the following statements

```
[[myListSet objectAtIndex:sender.tag] setValue:@"1" forKey:@"STATUS"];
```

where myListSet is defined as

```
NSMutableOrderedSet *myListSet;
```

myListSet is a list of dictionary entries, each with 6 key-value pairs, with one of the Keys being STATUS.

I thought I could update the values in one of the dictionaries using the above line.  It worked in simulator, but not on my iPhone.

The error I am getting is 
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'

I guess my thought on updating the entry is incorrect.  Any ideas on how to update a value for one of the keys for one of the dictionary entries in this set?

Comment: You want to use `setObject:forKey` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSMutableOrderedSet` allows you to modify its direct children. The error you are seeing arises because your `NSMutableOrderedSet` contains `NSDictionary` objects and not `NSMutableDictionary` objects.

In order to modify the sub-dictionaries, you will need them to be `NSMutableDictionary` objects. You could do this by:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[myListSet objectAtIndex:sender.tag]];
dict[@"STATUS"] = @"1";
[myListSet replaceObjectAtIndex:sender.tag withObject:dict];
```

You should be aware that anything that was holding a reference to the original immutable dictionary will still be holding that dictionary and not your modified dictionary.

Comment: This worked like a champ.  Thanks very much - I never have used NSMutableDictionary, but makes sense.   Great explanation and thanks for the sample.  It worked as is!

Answer (score 0):

setValue:forKey makes use of key-value coding which lets you set an object's properties. NSMutableOrderedSet doesn't come with a "STATUS" property out of the box.

You want to use setObject:forKey instead

Answer (score 0):

I believe your data structure is a set of NSDictionary. Your set is mutable but the dictionary within it is immutable.

If you have access to that dictionary then change NSDictionary to NSMutableDictionary and this will work. If not then

```
NSDictionary *myDictionary = [myListSet objectAtIndex:sender.tag];
NSDictionary *myMutableDictionary = [myDictionary mutableCopy];
[myMutableDictionary setValue:@"1" forKey:@"STATUS"];
[myListSet setObject:myMutableDictionary atIndex:sender.tag]
```